# How to configure and see API Statistics in WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to add API Analytics for my API and see the statistics like how request are calling a particular API.

I have uncommentes these lines from *deployment.toml* file

```
[apim.analytics]
enable = true
store_api_url = "https://localhost:7444"
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
event_publisher_type = "default"
event_publisher_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher"
publish_response_size = true
```

And if I open analytics dashboard there is *No Data Available !* message.

How to enable the statistics?

Screenshot of analytics dashboard

[image]

Comment: Did you run some API traffic to populate stats?

Comment: API traffic means calling some API's right..?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: In H2 default WSO2 database 'ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_PERMINUTEREQUEST' table is not getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Have you placed WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0 pack and WSO2 API Manager Analytics 3.0.0 pack in the same directory? If not you have to place both those packs in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, both are in same directory.